# Convex hull of set of points inside a half-space

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry, convex-geometry

We place ourselves in $\Bbb{R}^d$, for $d\geq 1$. Let $\mathcal{h}$ a hyperplane, and let $S$ be a finite set of points that all lie in one of the (closed) half-spaces limited by $h$.

Let $C$ denote transformation that to one set assigns its convex hull.

Prove that $C(S)\cap h=C(S\cap h )$.

Comment: What is $\mathcal H$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Sorry, $\mathcal{H}$ is the hyperplane limited by $h$ containing $S$. I also edited the second part.

Comment: Then the question is trivial... If all the points in $S$ are contain in one of the half-space, $S \cap h =\emptyset$

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I mean the closed half-space.

Comment: Please try to be more precise! Then my answer below is correct.

Comment: Please re-read the edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $S \cap h \subseteq h$ we have $C(S \cap h) \subseteq C(h)$ as $h$ is convex. And obviously $C(S \cap h) \subseteq C(S)$. Therefore $C(S \cap h) \subseteq C(S) \cap h$.

Regarding the converse inclusion. As $S$ is included in a half space having $h$ for boundary, a point $x$ belongs to $C(S) \cap h$ only if is is a convex combination of points of $S$. Otherwise it’s coordinate over a line not included in $h$ won’t vanishes in contradiction with $x \in h$. Hence $x$ is a convex combination of points of $S \cap h$ which means that $x \in C(S \cap h)$.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. I edited the question.

Comment: I updated my answer ... according to your question new version.